# Show that the following conclusion follows from the given premise.

Tags: logic

$\begin{array}{rl}
    & p \lor (q \rightarrow r) \\
    & q \lor r \\
    & r \rightarrow p \\
    \therefore & p
  \end{array}$

I am at my wits end with this one. I've tried simplifying $p \lor (q\rightarrow r)$ to $p \lor \lnot q \lor r$ but this doesn't lead me anywhere.  I also tried $\lnot r \lor p$ and just the combination of all that doesn't go anywhere. How do I use inference to prove this?

Comment: I don't know how to type the symbols, but you have two cases: (1) q. Then -q is false so either p or r. If r, then p. (2) -q. Then r by the second statement, then p by the third.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Use `\neg` for $\neg$, `\lor, \land` for $\lor, \land$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$p \lor (q \implies r) \quad ...(1)(Given)$$
$$p \lor (\neg q \lor r) \quad ...(2)(Definition)$$
$$(p \lor r) \lor \neg q \quad ...(3)(Associative)$$
$$q \lor r \quad ...(4)(Given)$$
$$(q \lor r) \lor p \quad ...(5)(Addition)$$
$$(p \lor r) \lor q \quad ...(6)(Associative)$$
$$ p \lor r \quad ...(7)(Disjunctive Syllogism (3), (6)) $$
$$ r \implies p \quad ...(8)(Given)$$
$$ \neg r \lor p \quad ...(9)(Definition)$$
$$ p \quad ...(Disjunctive Syllogism (7), (9)) $$

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the first statement is a good start.
We already know from the third statement that $p$ follows from $r$, so we only have to consider the case where $r$ is false, i.e. $\neg r$ holds.
But if that is the case, then either $p$ or $\neg q$ must be true.
Hence the only case left to argue is the one where $\neg r$ and $\neg q$ hold, but that yields a contradiction to the second statement.

It follows that $p$ must be true either way.

Comment: So we're supposed to do proof by cases to show all cases lead to p?

Comment: That is my strategy in this post. It is not the only one possible, but for this problem that is a simple approach.

Comment: I thought were were just supposed to push a bunch of symbols around and simplify until we get a single proposition which we can then use inference rules on. Proof by cases looks a lot easier. Thanks

Comment: You can certainly do that and there is value in working with a formalism like that, but yeah, sometimes arguing like this (essentially creating a truth table) is less work.